# is it possible to have a getter/setter template in c#?

Tags: c#, setter, getter

I want to apply this:

```
private string _name;

public string name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = Fix(value); }
}
```

to all string the members of a class, and don't want to repeat the same code for all the class members.

An obvious solution would be to put that code on a class to handle the problem and declare all string members as: `myString` instead of `string`, however that would mean that I would have to access the main class members like this: `email.fixed` instead of just `email`.

So I was wondering, is there is some kind of template I can define and then apply easily?

Comment: Just wanted to point out with Coderush the template access for this is ps -> spacebar.

Comment: Maybe you can write an add-on class for your IDE.

Comment: Are we talking about member which are fields, properties or both?

Comment: Code Snippets worked for me.  I made a version of propfull to include a call to the OnPropertyChanged() handler.  Much smoother.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) for Visual Studio to handle building a property this way.

MSDN includes documentation on [Creating a Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx), which can include replacement parameters (the name).

Comment: To be fair, code snippets are neither a feature of c# nor what is usually referred to as a "template"

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I'd actually consider a code snippet a template - I did explicitly mention that it's a feature of Visual Studio, though (and not the language) in my answer...

Comment: Fair enough, I +1ed your answer as there's a good chance it answers what the  OP is getting at. However my understanding of the term 'template' in this context is more akin to macros and I wanted to point out to the OP that snippets are not this.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Very true - this still leads to repeated code, but avoids the repeated typing ;)

Comment: I would advise to install a code snippet editor or creator which is available as a VS addin in `Tools->Extensions & Updates`. That process will create one without the pain of the learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to research Aspect Oriented Programming, which allows you to easily do things like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS

Comment: +1 for mentioning aspects. Unfortunately for the forseeable future the answer to the OPs question is "No" but there are many cool and useful things you can do with aspects. Word of warning though - it is a VERY heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a type with an implicit conversion to and from `string`:

```
public class FixedString
{
    private string str;
    public FixedString(string str){this.str = str;}
    public static implicit operator FixedString(string str)
    {
        return new FixedString(Fix(str));
    }
    public static implicit operator string(FixedString fixed)
    {
        return fixed.str;
    }
}
```

You can now create a property of this type, but treat it as if it's a string.

Comment: Personally, this is my preferred solution - In my case I have a large number of objects that are "load once" objects (as in, first time they are called they load a value, and from then on use the fixed value) and I don't want to repeat the loading process in each one. 
I wonder though if there is any way to block the access to the object as it's own type.
For example If have Cached<string> myString = new Cached<string>();
Then myString is of type Cached<string> and has to be cast to automatically show all the string methods. My point is I want the object to show as if it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a regex replace and use Visual Studio's (v2012/2013) find and replace regex functionality.

For example let us say you have a `field` like this to change into a property

```
public string Name;
```

and you want to change it to have a backing field and the setter you desire.

```
private string _Name;

public string Name 
{
   get { return _Name; }
   set { _Name = Fix(value); }
}
```

The find /replace regex pattern in Visual Studio to find is this

```
public\s+string\s([^;]+);
```

the replace pattern (with appropriate line spacings and tabs) is this

```
private string _$1;\r\n\r\n\tpublic string $1\r\n\t{\r\n\t\tget\r\n\t\t\t{ return _$1; }\r\n\t\tset\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t_$1 = Fix(value);\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t}
```

Then step through the finds and do a replace as needed within your class.

I have done similar to add INotifyChange method calls on blank properties created after doing the code snippet `<tab><tab>prop` action.